# Yet another positioning riddle

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have a two column list of items with square image and two lines of text next to it, nicely aligned

```
_________                                    ________
|       |                             |     |        |
|       |     Line one h3 tag         |     |        |     Line one h3 tag
|       |     Line two p tag          |     |        |     Line two p tag
|       |                             |     |        |
_________                             |     __________
```

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/PEMKs/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="right clearfix">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" >
        <h4>My name is Markup.</h4><p>I live in Vienna</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left ">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" >
        <h4>My name is Markup.</h4> <p>I live in Vienna</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
.wrapper{
    width:650px
}

.right{
    width:300px; 
    height:100px; 
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}

.right h4, .right p{
    float:right;
    margin-right:25px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.left{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:145px;
    border-right:1px dashed #cccccc;
}

.left h4, .left p{
float:right;
    margin-right:25px;
        font-family:sans-serif;
}

.clearfix:after {
   content: ".";
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

p{
 display:inline-block;   
}
```

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html What is your question?

Comment: @Emil: WDYM? It's pretty obvious what he wants, he has the ASCII graphics showing what he wants and a jsfiddle that's almost that but not quite...

Comment: Worst asked question ever. But this achieves what you are after with about a third of the css http://jsfiddle.net/PEMKs/5/

Comment: The only real thing wrong with your question was that you didn't include the code inside the question. You didn't deserve 6 downvotes. It took me all of 30 seconds to copy the code into the question; problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

How's this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/42XUW/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS style to your image

```
.left img { float: right;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="right clearfix">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="float:left;" >
        <h4>My name is Markup.</h4><p>I live in Vienna</p>
    </div>
    <div class="left ">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" style="float:left;" >
        <h4>My name is Markup.</h4> <p>I live in Vienna</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

the style of the image will be set to float:left. It solves your problem.